# JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'SM2T' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

Hi I am trying to IBM MQ using JMS. I am getting below error

> JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'SM2T' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'

Here is my code:

```
public void putMessageToqueue() throws JMSException {
        JMSContext context = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        JMSProducer producer = null;
        JMSConsumer consumer = null;
        
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, queueHost);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, queueChannel);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, queueUser);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, queueUser);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
        cf.setStringProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
        cf.setStringProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", trustStore);
        cf.setStringProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "");
        cf.setStringProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        
        
        context = cf.createContext();
        destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + queueName);

        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);
        producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(destination, message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

                    context.close();

        //recordSuccess();
        
    }
```

Comment: Here the main issue is Hostname is coming as null

Comment: Are you initializing variable queueHost?

Comment: Yes i intialized as like all other variables

Comment: If you are still unable to determine the problem, please update your question to show the code that initializes the variables.

Comment: private static String trustStore = "C:\\ssl\\MQDEV.jks";
 private String cipherSuite="TSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
 private static String queueHost="xxx";
 private static String queueManager="SM2T";
 private static Integer port=1404;
 private static String queueChannel="xxx";
 private static String queueName="xxx";
 private static String queueUser="TMQMTS50";
 private static String queuePassword="TMQMTS50";

Comment: Please don't paste code in comments. Use [edit] link below the question.

Comment: There is a linked exception that can be captured also, can you please capture and provide that.   Please edit the question to add information such as additional code or errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of issues with your code.  It looks like you copied & pasted code from a couple of different sources but you left out some important code.

***Problems:***

1. I don't see where you created a connection
2. I don't see where you started the connection
3. I don't see where you created a session
4. The TLS/SSL trusted store & key store values do not belong to the connection factory but rather they should be JVM system environment variables.

i.e.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustedStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustedStorePasswd);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePasswd);
```

Also, if you are using a trusted store or key store then it ***MUST*** have a valid password.  And you only need a key store if you are using mutual authentication.

5. The IBM Cipher Mappings value does not belong to the connection factory but rather it should be JVM system environment variable.

i.e.

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
```

Note: JVM system environment variables can be externized to the Java application and passed on the command line.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mytrustedstore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mytrustedstorepwd -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false blah blah blah
```

Here is a fully functioning MQ/JMS application that builds the connection factory from scratch.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.*;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.*;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQTestJMS51
 *
 * Description
 *  This java JMS class will connect to a remote queue manager and put a message to a queue.
 *  This code will create the Connection Factory from scratch.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQTestJMS51
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat  LOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   private Hashtable<String,String> params;

   public MQTestJMS51()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      
      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (!allParamsPresent())
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Create a connection to the queue manager then publish a message to a queue.
    */
   private void handleIt() 
   {
      Connection conn = null;
      Session session = null;
      Destination destination = null;
      MessageProducer producer = null;
      
      try
      {
         /*
          * Set JVM system environment variables
          */
         System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
         
//         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustedStore);
//         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustedStorePasswd);
         
         JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
         JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

         // Set the properties
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, (String) params.get("-h"));
         try
         {
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p")));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
         }
         
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, (String) params.get("-c"));
         cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, (String) params.get("-m"));
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "MQTestJMS51");
         cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
         
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, (String) params.get("-u"));
         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, (String) params.get("-x"));
         
//         cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
         
         conn = cf.createConnection((String) params.get("-u"), (String) params.get("-x"));
         logger("created connection.");
         
         // Start the connection
         conn.start();
         logger("started connection.");

         session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         logger("created session.");

         /*
          * targetClient=0 means it is sending a JMS message
          * targetClient=1 means it is sending an MQ message (non JMS)
          */
         destination = session.createQueue("queue://" + (String) params.get("-m") + "/" + (String) params.get("-q") + "?targetClient=0");
         logger("created destination.");

         producer = session.createProducer(destination);
         logger("created producer.");
         
         sendMsg(session, producer);
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         if (e != null)
         {
            logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            Exception gle = e.getLinkedException();
            if (gle != null)
               logger(gle.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (producer != null)
            {
               producer.close();
               logger("closed producer.");
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            logger("producer.close() : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            if (session != null)
            {
               session.close();
               logger("closed session.");
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            logger("session.close() : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            if (conn != null)
            {
               conn.stop();
               logger("stopped connection.");
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            logger("conn.stop() : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            if (conn != null)
            {
               conn.close();
               logger("closed connection.");
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            logger("connection.close() : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Send a message to a queue.
    */
   private void sendMsg(Session session, MessageProducer producer)
   {
      try
      {
         long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
         TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

         producer.send(msg);
         logger("Sent message: " + msg);
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         if (e != null)
         {
            logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            Exception gle = e.getLinkedException();
            if (gle != null)
               logger(gle.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ( (className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) )
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println(LOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date())+" "+className+": "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+": "+data);
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      logger("starting...");
      try
      {
         MQTestJMS51 tj = new MQTestJMS51();
         tj.init(args);
         tj.handleIt();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         logger("Usage: java MQTestJMS51 -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -q Queue_Name -u UserID -x Password");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         logger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      logger("ending...");
   }
}
```