# IBM MQ connection using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Good Day,

I am struggling with below error when trying to connect to IBM MQ. Unable to access createContext(); and forces me to use  **(JMSContext) cf.createConnection();** which is resulting me error as below:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection cannot be cast to javax.jms.JMSContext
at pushmsgs.main(pushmsgs.java:55)"

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

import javax.jms.*;

public class pushmsgs {

    // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
    private static int status = 1;

    // Create variables for the connection to MQ
    private static final String HOST = "22.188.133.100"; // Host name or IP address
    private static final int PORT = 3415; // Listener port for your queue manager
    private static final String CHANNEL = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"; // Channel name
    private static final String QMGR = "SITQUEUEMGR"; // Queue manager name
   // private static final String APP_USER = "app"; // User name that application uses to connect to MQ
    //private static final String APP_PASSWORD = "_APP_PASSWORD_"; // Password that the application uses to connect to MQ
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "TESTQUEUE.MQAPP.REQ.RCV"; // Queue that the application uses to put and get messages to and from


    /**
     * Main method
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Variables
        JMSContext context = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        JMSProducer producer = null;
        JMSConsumer consumer = null;



        try {
            // Create a connection factory
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

            // Set the properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
           // cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
            //cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
           // cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
            //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);
            //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "*TLS12");

            // Create JMS objects
            context = (JMSContext) cf.createConnection();
            destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

            long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

            producer = context.createProducer();
            producer.send(destination, message);
            System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

            context.close();

            recordSuccess();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }

        System.exit(status);

    } // end main()

    /**
     * Record this run as successful.
     */
    private static void recordSuccess() {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        status = 0;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Record this run as failure.
     *
     * @param ex
     */
    private static void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
        status = -1;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Process a JMSException and any associated inner exceptions.
     *
     * @param jmsex
     */
    private static void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
        System.out.println(jmsex);
        Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
        if (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println("Inner exception(s):");
        }
        while (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println(innerException);
            innerException = innerException.getCause();
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

[image]

Added JMS mvn dependency and com.ibm.mq.allclient dependency

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are assigning the wrong object to the wrong variable.

```
context = (JMSContext) cf.createConnection();
```

I don't know why you would want to do that.  A connection is not a context.

It should be:

```
Connection conn = cf.createConnection("MyUserId", "mypassword");
```

See my example called MQTestJMS51 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625629/jmswmq0018-failed-to-connect-to-queue-manager-sm2t-with-connection-mode-clie/69668688#69668688).